# Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

mysql Master and  Slave are not synchronization.

```html
mysql> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: 192.168.2.92
                  Master_User: rep
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binlog.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 248
               Relay_Log_File: Slave-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binlog.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 248
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql>
```

below is Master my.cnf:

```html
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /opt/data/mysql/data
character-set-server = utf8
skip-external-locking
log-slow-queries = /opt/data/mysql/slow_logs
long_query_time = 5
log-queries-not-using-indexes
expire_logs_days=7
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 10M
max_connections = 1000
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log-bin=/opt/data/mysql/bin_log/mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
server-id       = 1
innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 100M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

below is Slave my.cnf:

```html
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /opt/data/mysql/data
character-set-server = utf8
skip-external-locking
log-slow-queries = /opt/data/mysql/slow_logs
long_query_time = 5
log-queries-not-using-indexes
expire_logs_days=7
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 10M
max_connections = 1000
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log-bin=/opt/data/mysql/bin_log/mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
server-id       = 3
innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 100M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

on Master:
show master status\G;
grant replication slave on *.* to 'beifen'@'%' identified by '123';

On Slave:

change master to master_host='192.168.2.92',master_user='beifen',master_password='123',master_log_file='binlog.000008',master_log_pos=107; 
start slave;

but:show slave status\G;
Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'

I try to reset slave,flush logs on slave but ,the problem is Still Existence.
how to slove it?

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but did you ever solve this?